# How can I set up a crontab job to run Monday to Saturday 5am?

Tags: cron

i want to crontab run Monday to Saturday 5 am.

```
*/1 * * * * sleep 1; chart1_min.sh
```

but this cronjob is only execute every 1 min.

i want to try another way.

how can i solve this problem?

i can't understand crontab's complex conditions

Please give a good solution

Very thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Read man with
Man 5 crontab.
What you are asking:

```
 Minute hour day month dayweek
0 5 * * 1-6 sleep 1; chart1_min.sh
```